# WSO2 Synchronizing of tiers.xml b/w manager and worker nodes

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm running on cluster where manager (publisher, store, km, etc) is on one node and gateway workers are on other nodes. I'm using SVN synchronizer to sync between them, and indeed API's published on the manager are added properly to the gateway.

I also use tiers.xml for setting up rate limit for unauthenticated API's. This is done by changing the registry resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml at the manager node.

```
        <throttle:ID throttle:type="ROLE">Unauthenticated</throttle:ID>
        <wsp:Policy>
            <throttle:Control>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <throttle:MaximumCount>1000</throttle:MaximumCount>
                    <throttle:UnitTime>60000</throttle:UnitTime>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </throttle:Control>
        </wsp:Policy>
```

However, changes done to this tiers.xml are not populated to worker nodes, so if I change maximum count in tiers.xml at the manager - this rate limit is not affecting the worker node.

Any idea how to populate tiers.xml changes to worker nodes?

Comment: In the following guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/shared/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+a+Remote+Registry it seems that registry.xml needs to be configured for remote registry. It is not clear, though, if I have to create additional datasource for it, in addition the one I'm already use for registry and user management, and how to create it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tiers.xml, being part of the registry, is not synchronized by SVN. This is done as explained in the following document: https://docs.wso2.com/display/shared/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+a+Remote+Registry

Regarding database setup, instructions can be found here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+the+Database

The information is valid for carbon version 4.4.x, APIM-1.10. My understanding is that in APIM-2 there are changes/improvement, but I did not upgrade to release 2 yet.